# Seeking software to pick up rectangular shape of basketball courts?

Tags: remote-sensing, software-recommendations, classification, digital-image-processing, rgb

Is there any software/plugins for remote sensing or object orientated classification for my 3 band aerial image? I want the program to be able to pick up open air basketball courts or badminton courts (Unsupervised classification preferred).

I've tried using GRASS GIS Image classification method but did not get the results I hoped get as it was only good in identifying buildings.

I've also tried the SCP Plugin for QGIS but is not suitable for a 3 band image.

Comment: eCognition is a poweful software for object oriented classifiction and 3 Bands images.  http://www.ecognition.com/

Comment: @wetland Thanks for the reply! i will try using ecognition's free trial .

Answer (score 1):

You can use Orfeo toolbox (Image Analysis) which is a free software that can be installed from [OSGeo4W Network Installer](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html) and use it from inside QGIS. Orfeo Toolbox has many functions for image analysis including Segmentation, Image classification, feature extraction among others as you can see below:

[image]

Orfeo toolbox is not installed by default into QGIS. You need to install it as additional tool from OSGeo4W advanced installer.

[image]

I did not use it for image classification, but you can try and see if it can solve you problem.